# Select text within tags in textarea javascript and vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, textarea

I have been working on a problem that I havent solved yet.
What I have is text in an textarea and the words that has **[** at the start and **]** at the end will get selected and then jump to the next word and select it.

So I have manage to get it to get the text inside the brackets but how do i move and select that text and the jump to the next word. I have an idea to use setSelectionRange(); some how.

Here is my code so far:

```
var driftError = ['Move over and select [this] then write something and select [this here]'];

Vue.component('template-maker',{
    template: '\
    <div>\
    <b>Select template</b><br>\
    <select id="templates" v-on:change="appendData">\
<option selected disabled></option>\
<option>Error template</option>\
    </select>\<br>\
    <b>Text</b><br>\
    <textarea id="templateText" v-on:click="test"/>\
    </div>\
    ',
    methods:{
        appendData: function(){
            var templateText = document.getElementById('templateText');
            templateText.innerHTML = driftError[0];
        },
        test: function(){
    if(templateText.value.length != 0){
      var markupExtract = driftError[0].split('[');
      var inputLen = templateText.value.length;
      for (var i = 1; i < markupExtract.length; i++) {
          alert(markupExtract[i].split(']')[0]);
                        //templateText.setSelectionRange(0,markupExtract[i].split(']')[0].length));
      }
    }
        }
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#template',
})
```

You can test it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/amrw0rer/

Comment: Do you only want the text pointer to jump to the position? When should the second "jump" come up? After pressing space?

Comment: @FrankProvost maybe tab is better or arrow-up because if you write two words space will be a probem i think

Comment: So you actually want the rest of the text not to be editable?

Comment: yes. when textarea gets focus the first word with bracket around get selected  and when you wrote some text some key is pressed and it moves to the next word with brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be done in a simple way as you might imagine it (just setting pointers etc). Without major changes to your example you will not be able to achieve what you want. I prepered a really really really small example of how you could do it. There are no checks and this should never ever be used as I did it in any productive way - it's just as a sample to clarify the idea.

https://jsfiddle.net/amrw0rer/1/

What you could and probably should actually do is to put input fields inbetween the non-editable text parts. The sample shows it for one input - it won't work with two because of the string splitting part.

The enhancement would be to put the input field always at the position you are currently allowed to change.

```
 <span>{{ textBeforeInput }}</span><input v-model="newText" /><span>{{ textAfterInput}}</span>
```

You might event want to wrap the input into a form and listen to the submit event to change to the next pointer. The only thing you then need to do is to update the textBefore and textAfterInput values and save the newText to wherevery you need it.

Comment: Ok. Does it make any difference if all the text was possible to edit. Now if you put more brackets in the template it only gets the first and sets it as a input field

Comment: as said it is a rough example of how to dot it. You'll need to improve the string splitting. I'm not aware of a cross browser way to set pointers within the textarea.